# Returning an array created in another method

Tags: java, arrays, methods, global, local

Due to assignment restrictions, there is an array that I need to be able to return via a getter method (i.e. getArray()) that must be created locally within another method (because its size is dependent on other functions in that method).  Essentially I have a fixed capacity array that I fill up with tokens taken from user input, which then needs to create another array the exact size as the number of tokens (no more null values).  For some reason the smaller array has to be created in the method that scans the input for tokens, but I don't know how I can then pass the final array to the getter method since I can't globally initialize the size of the array.

Edit:
I do create the smaller array with a global variable.  That variable starts at zero and increments each time a token is found so the smaller array is the appropriate size. Assignment rules force me to declare the array within the method that does the scanning, because of this the array is forced to be local.  It must be declared within the scanning method and returned within the getter method, and I don't know how to reconcile the two.

I use an object array because the array items are various similar but different objects.

```
int itemsScanned = 0;

public void scanStuff(){
//does the scanning

    Object[] array = new Object[itemsScanned]
    int arrayIndex = 0;
    while (arrayIndex < itemsScanned){
        array[arrayIndex] = largeArray[arrayIndex];
        arrayIndex++;
    }
}

public Object[] getArray(){
    return array
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "globally initialize the size of the array"? You can initialize an array to a given size with a variable.

Comment: Please post what you came up with till now - it will be more clear where you got stuck

Comment: Java do not have global variables. Do you mean class variables (static variables)? It is better if you show your classes.

Answer (score 0):

Right now `array` is a local variable. It won't be available to other methods. You will need to make it a *field* on the class.

```
class A {
    Object[] array;
    public void scan() {
        array = new Object[]{this};
    }

    public Object[] getArray() {
        return array;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to use the scan method several times, does that declaration let me define the array's size for different amounts of elements in each scan?

Comment: `array` is just a pointer to an Array. Notice how I created a new array and assigned it to the reference in `scan()`. The size is just whatever the real array is. Note that this code won't be safe for use with multiple threads.